# Comma Problem: I removed the commas from this sentence because I can't determine where to put them and was hoping for some help

Tags: commas

Your relationships change based on the decisions you make when talking with each crewmember and in a few specific instances with decisions you make on which mission to take or how to resolve a particularly difficult decision during a mission.

Comment: My real question is if the 'and' should be offset (commas before and after and).  I would normally use only one comma after the conjunction, but I never feel quite certain about it.

Comment: It's a clumsy meandering sentence in the first place, and I don't think adding commas will do much to aid comprehension. The structure is so complex it's even led you the author to get confused about what exactly you're saying. Consider carefully why you've got ***with*** before the second occurrence of ***decisions*** (the only explanation I can come up with is your *words* are too complex for you to follow, regardless of any possible punctuation).

Comment: I hate that sentence soooo much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence needs at least a break:

*Your relationships change based on the decisions you make when talking with each crew member. **In** **a few specific** instances, **these could be decisions** you make on which mission to take or how to **/implement/effect/** a particularly difficult decision during a mission.*

This offers both a break and some clarity, separating a specific batch of decisions from the whole.

More direct:

*Your relationships **change by**  the decisions you make when talking with each crew member. **Sometimes**, **[these are]** decisions you make on which mission to take. **Sometimes**, **[they are]** decisions on how to how to **/implement/effect/** a particularly difficult decision during a mission.*

Answer (score 1):

It looks to be a pretty long sentence, but inserting a couple of commas should be fine:

> Your relationships change based on the decisions you make when talking with each crewmember, and in a few specific instances with decisions you make on which mission to take, or how to resolve a particularly difficult decision during a mission.

Comment: A super-comma (which looks astonishingly like a semicolon) might be preferred before the _and_ to show hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the main problem with the sentence isn't the punctuation (or lack therof) but with the false parallelism of the pair of "with" phrases. On a first reading, it is very easy to go off-trail by supposing that the author intends to establish parallelism after the word *talking*:

> Your relationships change based on the decisions you make when talking (1) with each crewmember and (2) [in a few specific instances] with decisions you make on which mission to take or how to resolve a particularly difficult decision during a mission.

Upon realizing that no such parallelism is intended, the reader must then look for the parallel structure that the author did mean to establish, which turns out to follow the word *change*. The author could make this clearer by swapping out the second "with" in favor of "based on":

> Your relationships change (1) based on the decisions you make when talking with each crewmember and [in a few specific instances] based on decisions you make on which mission to take or how to resolve a particularly difficult decision during a mission.

Now the sentence is reasonably clear until we get to this block of prose:

> on which mission to take or how to resolve a particularly difficult decision during a mission.

The chief problem in this part of the sentence is the sense of the expression

> decisions you make on ... how to resolve a particularly difficult decision ...

Normally we don't make decisions to resolve decisions; we make decisions to solve difficulties or to adopt a course of action. So the sentence would be much better off if the author replaced "a particularly difficult decision" with "a particular difficulty":

> Your relationships change based on the decisions you make when talking with each crewmember and in a few specific instances based on decisions you make as to which mission to take or how to resolve a particular difficulty that arises during a mission.

Now that the wording makes more sense, we can consider what punctuation (if any) might help the reader follow the logic of the sentence. In my opinion, the sentence doesn't need any internal punctuation, although its structure might be marginally easier to grasp if you set off the phrase "in a few specific instances" with commas:

> Your relationships change based on the decisions you make when talking with each crewmember and, in a few specific instances, based on decisions you make as to which mission to take or how to resolve a particular difficulty that arises during a mission.